# df aggregate and list factors if one column is unique

Tags: r, aggregate, unique

I got the following df and a bit stuck at the moment:

```
df1
X1    X2    X3    X4
A     1     a     x
A     2     a     x
A     3     a     y
B     1     b     x
...
```

and I am trying to aggregate the df so that I have a unique value IF X4 is the same so I want this:

```
df2
X1    X2    X3    X4
A     1,2   a     x
A     3     a     y
B     1     b     x
...
```

I tried this:

```
df2 <-aggregate(.~X1,df1,unique)
```

but it doesn't really work. X2 is also a numerical value, but I want it listed as if it were a character (transformed it into character).

Can someone help?

Comment: You may need `aggregate(.~ X1, df1, function(x) toString(unique(x)))`

Comment: Or `aggregate(.~ X1 + X3 + X4, df1, function(x) toString(unique(x)))`

Comment: thank you that already solved the problem with the numerical value!
But is there a way to assure that its only aggregated according to X1 IF X4 is all the same?

Comment: okay it worked with `aggregate(.~ X1+X4, df1, function(x) toString(unique(x)))`

Answer (score 0):

We can `paste` the `unique` elements

```
aggregate(.~ X1, df1, function(x) toString(unique(x)))
```